# Variable has been Initialized in Scala class, but what it print is null?

Tags: scala

```
object ObjectExample {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val student = new Student("zhu", 18, "zz")
    println(student.gender)
  }
}

class People(val name: String, val age: Int) {
  println("constructor")
  println(name)
  val gender: String = "male"
  println(gender)
  def this(name1: String) = {  //it is useless in here
    this("ci", 18)
    println("subconstructor")
    println(name)
    println(gender)
  }
}


class Student(name: String, age: Int, val school: String) extends People(name, age){
  println("derived constructor")
  println(name)
  println(school)
  override val gender: String = "female"
  println(gender)
}
```

the first `gender` which I think I have already Initialized, But What it print is null. I try to overwrite it in `Student` class and it print "female".

here are results, the third line is what `People`'s `gender` output

```
constructor
zhu
null
derived constructor
zhu
zz
female
female
```

Comment: Well... class members are a bit different from normal variables. Since the `Student` class has a member `gender` which overrides the `gender` from parent class, the constructor of Student will omit this `val gender: String = "male"` declaration and will keep only `val gender: String = "female"` but this statement has not executed yet. So the result will be the null value for `gender`.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh That looks like an answer, why not add it as an answer and get the credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think section **5.1.4 Overriding** of the [language spec](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/05-classes-and-objects.html) has the pertinent information.

> ...the binding of the overriding member ... must subsume the binding of the overridden member...

What's more, I believe the **Early Definitions** syntax was designed to address this issue.

```
class Student(name: String, age: Int, val school: String
             ) extends {override val gender = "female"} with People(name, age) {
  println("derived constructor")
  println(name)
  println(school)
  //override val gender: String = "female"
  println(gender)
}
```

Now the output has no `null`.

```
constructor
zhu
female
derived constructor
... (etc.)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is explained in [Scala FAQ - Why is my abstract or overriden val null?](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html)

Citation from page:

> A ‘strict’ or ‘eager’ val is one which is not marked lazy.
>
> In the absence of “early definitions” (see below), initialization of strict vals is done in the following order.
>
> Superclasses are fully initialized before subclasses.
>   Otherwise, in declaration order.
>   Naturally when a val is overridden, it is not initialized more than once. So though x2 in the above example is seemingly defined at every point, this is not the case: an overridden val will appear to be null during the construction of superclasses, as will an abstract val.
>
> There is a compiler flag which can be useful for identifying this situation:
>
> -Xcheckinit: Add runtime check to field accessors.

Page also offers three solutions (see FAQ page for details):

1. Use lazy vals
2. Use early definitions (as @jwvh already suggested)
3. Use constant value definitions